# Presenting a date picker (calendar) that span multiple months

Tags: web, dates, calendar

The system I am working on allows users to post events and find events they wish to go to.  Currently, events are very rarely submitted more than 2 months in advance, so allowing a user to scroll into the future beyond that serves no real purpose.  The majority of events are in the system roughly 1 month in advance.  This behavior may or may not change in the future as the userbase grows.

My gut says that a calendar is going to be the best way to present a collection of dates that have events so that they can quickly find out what's happening on a specific date, but I am open to other options.  Here are the mock-ups I've been exploring (dates that have events will appear different from dates without events, and the starting week is dictated by today's date):

## A 5-week Calendar

This looks most like what people expect when they think *calendar*, but only covers the highest concentration of events.  If there are 2 different months filling the calendar, they will be colored differently.

[image]

## An 8-week Calendar

This covers the majority of events that are upcoming, but looks a little weird to me.  Again, different coloring for different months.

[image]

## An 8-week Calendar, split by month

I am favoring this one, since the divisions feel right, but it takes up a little more space than I was hoping to allocate for the element.

[image]

I'm not sure from a technology standpoint how easy it would be for me to pull multiple entire months out of the database.  Even if I could, the dates would likely show as not having an event anyway, and would just be a waste of space.

Are there other options I could be exploring or am I on the right track with what I have?

Related:  [In a calendar, should we show dates that fall outside the current month?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44059/in-a-calendar-should-we-show-dates-that-fall-outside-the-current-month)

Comment: You shouldn't present collection of dates, instead present events. Nearest event (~2 weeks) widget (short horizon) and separate page with detailed calendar-event data (long horizon) could be better option.

Comment: Viewing events by date is not the only aggregate in place in my application.  There are multiple views, including chronologically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DatePicker UX for single and multiple calendar mode](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30560/datepicker-ux-for-single-and-multiple-calendar-mode)

Answer (score 2):

If you really need pure calendar view widget you could try the following idea:
[image]

Features:

- Familiar calendar view
- Economic screen space
- Amount of events is visible in advance

Still, pure calendar widget works well for dense event flow. You could think out-of-the-box and use more suitable [Event Calendar pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/EventCalendar), which more close to @bendataclear answer. There you could find section of *a Common pitfalls of event calendar design*, which could be useful to you.

<sub>Image source: [Event Calendar Pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/EventCalendar)</sub>
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A calendar is great for picking a date but I find a calendar a bit tricky to use for displaying information, if you choose a small cell size you have a very small space but a big cell size limits the data you can display.
Also as you say you have a lot of wasted space where there are no events.

I would suggest a event list that you can collapse and expand (similar to Facebook's timeline) which would only show years/months where there were events:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvD2rT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: This seems like a less than ideal way of quickly finding out what's happening on a specific date.

Comment: @cimmanon You really need to be clear on the usage, will the users be searching for a specific event? looking at a specific date? looking for an event in a date range or specific month?